# Tinker always returning not found in eval() Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have my Models Place in App/Models, and if i attempt to run in tinker:

```
$user = new App\User;
or
$user = new App\Models\User;
```

i am shown with:

```
Class x not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

I also found out the following does not work either:

```
$user = new User();
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: same code worked for me, just make sure that User model exists...

Comment: Yes it's working now not sure what happened

Comment: can be used 

$user  = new \App\User;

or  if you rename your app  with php artisan app:name  THE_NEW_NAME  you must use   


$user  = new \THE_NEW_NAME\User;

Answer (score 0):

you can try this instead.

hope it'll help

`$user = new \App\User;`

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try running `php artisan optimize` in the terminal and restart tinker, which resolved the error for me. I continued experiencing this error message in v5.4.32 after prepending the full namespace. Hope that helps.